# Creating simple RewriteRule

Tags: php, regex, apache, url, url-rewriting

I want to create a RewriteRule that transforms websitedomain/index.php?parameter1=something1&parameter2=something2 in websitedomain/something1/something2. Thanks everybody in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)
```

That should be your pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?parameter1=$1&parameter2=$2 [L,QSA]
```